# ASP.NET Forms Parameters on Links

Tags: asp.net

Ok, let me start this with I am more of an MVC person.  I have a result set that I am trying to add paging.  All I really want is a previous and next button on my page which are Link controls.  I need these controls to post back to the same page, but have a query parm like page=4.  How do I add these links?  I see the PostBackUrl property on the link.  Should I just use Request.Url and stuff it into PostBackUrl?  Then I have to do string searches on the parm... it gets nasty.  Is that the only way?  I have tried ViewState, please dont suggest that... it is unpredictable garbage as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Do you want to do something like this? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx

Comment: Also, do you literally mean you need a POST or do you want to GET?

Comment: Yes - i don't see a need for a POST here, if you're just redirecting to another URL with QS. All the info for the request is in the QS - just use a regular link with HTTP GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostBackUrl property is for cross-page postbacks, you don't want to do that.

If you want to use a POST, you can use a LinkButton, handle the click event, and rebind your result set.  Something like

```
public void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Get existing page from session, viewstate, etc
  // RebindGrid
}
```

If you want to use a GET, you can use a HyperLink and set the NavigateUrl property to the correct Url.  Something like

```
int page;
if( !int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out page) )
  page = 1;

if( page > 1 )
  BackUrl.NavigateUrl = Request.Path + "?page=" + (page-1).ToString();
else
  NextUrl.NavigateUrl = Request.path + "?page=" + (page+1).ToString(); 
// Note: not syntax/bounds checked
```

---

Edit:
Perhaps what you're looking for a [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path + query, true);
```

Comment: What I want is really to just do a post back, but append a get parm... so its both.

Comment: I am going to mark you for the answer because you gave some great links and ideas.

Comment: If you've got some more questions I'll try to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about ASP.NET Webforms or MVC?

If you're talking about Webforms I don't think that you'll have success on that. I believe that you'll need to control this move between your pagination with Session or other way or re-bind your data for each page.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was putting hiddens on the page for the vars I needed to pass back, then I read those.  This is things like page number, which allows me to calculate prev and next page.  Sorry to submit my own answer but this was a little odd and I thought I would tell what I ended up doing.

View state for some reason was empty every time, so it was doing me no good.  This is in a DNN app, and I didnt want to spend time figuring out why viewstate was messed up.